# Modifications to the layout engine must not be performed from a background thread on iOS 17 and above

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, autolayout

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Modifications to the layout engine must not be performed from a background thread after it has been accessed from the main thread.
Unsupported layout off the main thread for UITextEffectsWindow with no associated or ancestor view controller

I have been experiencing frequent crashes on iOS 17 and above recently, and I'm having trouble pinpointing the source of the crashes. The crash logs provide no information about the specific location of the crashes. Is there any workaround or solution to identify and resolve this issue?

Please find attached the crash logs below

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58087536/modifications-to-the-layout-engine-must-not-be-performed-from-a-background-thr) could help you find the issue causing the crash.

Comment: I have enabled the main thread checker, but the breakpoint is still not hitting when the crash occurs. Unfortunately, the backtrace does not provide any information about the source. I am unsure where the crash might be happening in the source code. @tomerpacific